# Way to find differentiate between a string used as a name of a variable and a regular string

Tags: javascript, parsing

Edit: Your comments have convinced me I am attempting this problem with the completely wrong approach. I can't search simply if a string has quotes around it because of the way I am splitting up the code. Thank you sincerely for all your help.

I am trying to make a js "uglier" (based on beautify). Right now I'm parsing through my js file and replacing all occurrences of a variable with their randomized new name. It is worth noting I am working on functions right now, so I get the name of the variable that I want to change, I get the variable "x" here.

```
function example(varname)
```

The problem is, when I use file.replace to replace all occurrences of this variable, if I have a string or function named it, it will replace it as well. EX:

```
function example(varname) {
    return varname;
}
function varname() {
print("varname")
}
```

In the example, every instance of varname will be replaced with the random string. How can I only replace varnames that are being used as variable names.

Comment: Well all strings have to be quoted. Why not use that information to tell the difference?

Comment: You should try and solve this on your own first. Show your attempt, describe how it fails. Also: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

Comment: use a regular expression to check if the varname is present somewhere inside double or single quotes.

Comment: You should check how similar tools work first - [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS), for example. Most of the time they generate abstract syntax tree from code, then transform AST correspondingly. Brute-force regexing won't take you much further, as you'll have to differentiate between comments, properties of object etc.